# What is the approach to solve the following differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(1-x^2)y_2 +xy_1 -y = x(1-x^2)^{3/2}$$

Where $y_2 = \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ and $y_1 = \frac{dy}{dx}$.

Please provide some ideas/hints to approach this kind of problem in general in place of providing complete solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the square root in RHS, we need $(1-x^2)\ge 0\iff x\in[-1,1]$.

This group also suggests a trigonometric substitution for instance : $x=\sin(t)$.

But before that, Wolfram Alpha recognize it as a Sturm-Liouville equation, so let's substitute $y=ux$.

This leads to homogeneous equation to $(1-x^2)xu''+(2-x^2)u'=0$

Giving : $y=Ax-B\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}+x\arcsin(x)\right)$

I let you have fun, searching for a particular solution with the RHS.